# Didn't update the database automatically after computation

Tags: php, mysql

I have a computation of scores coming from different table.
The problem is, the database didn't update automatically when I insert new score and when the final score change..

I tried to use trigger but I got errors because I don't know the right way on how to implement it..

[image]

The $firsttransgrade is the final score..

this is the trigger I tried before

```
<?php include('../db.php'); $queryfirst = mysql_query("CREATE TRIGGER onupdate BEFORE UPDATE ON student_subject FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SET NEW.first = NEW.$firsttransgrade WHERE idnumber='$idnumber'               AND subject='$subject' AND section='$section' AND level='$level' AND year='$year' AND teacher='$login_session' ; END;") or die("Query failed: ".mysql_error());?>
```

and here's the error

```
Query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE idnumber='1111' AND subject='filipino' AND section='amihan' at line 4
```

Comment: what is your error and where is your trigger? Pleas post code instead of screenshot.

Comment: don't see where `$idnumber`, `$subject` etc are set

Comment: I sincerely hope this isn’t production code. Please make sure that all those variables that are being substituted into the query are properly escaped; otherwise, you’ve got an SQL injection vulnerability. Beyond that, while not a security problem, the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated in favor of PDO or mysqli.

Comment: echo the mysql query and run it in mysql workbench or phpmyadmin